# Entirely Different Functions.php per Page?

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

Is it possible via conditionals to load entirely different functions?

i.e in the functions.php you have a conditional that loads in an include for the old functions, then another that loads in the new?

The reason for this is a site is taking on a new look but only page by page, the old styles and functions are a mess and need replacing but i cannot just remove them as the rest of the site will fail.

Comment: I have one question here, why don't you redesign your complete site offline on localhost, and once completely done, just upload everything back. I think this might be less complicated and much easier to keep track of as oppose to writing and implementing other unnessesary functions. This is just my though on this

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible, the current site has to remain live and then news pages appear alongside at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`functions.php` will load automatically for every page load, but you could certainly move most of the content of your current `functions.php` to other files and use `functions.php` itself as a primarily a kind of switch.

*Caveat*: You may have to hook some of your switching functions to get access to certain data. For example, `functions.php` executes before the main query (which is why the `pre_get_post` hook works if called from there) so things dependent on the main query won't be set correctly in `functions.php`.

Comment: If someone is asking this question I'm guessing they don't have enough PHP/Programming experience to see why/how this should work. It's pretty obvious to anyone that has built a custom theme or plugin, but a code example might be useful. Otherwise this answer is about as good as it gets. :)

Comment: @totels : without knowing what switch conditions the OP needs a code example isn't really possible. The best I could do is a generic `switch` or `if`/`ifelse`/`else` which that can be found in the PHP docs.

Comment: How would this work within the admin side though, as some functions effect that? SO if you have functions 1 & functions 2 depending on what page there will be duplicate functions for the admin as they won’t be separated...

Comment: You would have to have conditions to manage loading on the backend too. This could get quite complicated. You are in for a painful job and a proper development path on a local server is probably the best idea. For the most part, I agree with @pietergoosen on that.

Comment: I don’t have that luxury unfortunately, the client wants the existing pages to look the same & the new to run alongside....

Comment: What you want is possible, but painful, and this should get you part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new single post template and only use it on new posts you publish.

All the code in this file will only execute on these posts.

You can also add conditionals to the file or via your child themes functions file.

The file can also include a custom body class.